# How to write mockito junit for the method below:

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

Help

```
@Override
public String postRequestinTransactionService(String data) {
    RequestTransaction request = new RequestTransaction(data.getClass().getName(), data);
    HttpEntity<RequestTransaction> entity = new HttpEntity<RequestTransaction>(request);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(this.urlTransactions, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
            String.class);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post codes and efforts!

Comment: that is a very trivial method + test, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: what is the way to do the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is barebone test class for you. You can write test case and if you have specific problem then ask question.

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class YourClassNameTest{

    @InjectMocks
    YourClassUnderTest myClass;
    private String data;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    //prepare you data here
    // any other mock action you can set here
    }

    @Test
    public void testPostRequestinTransactionService() throws Exception {
    //Write you test here
    String result=myClass.postRequestinTransactionService(data);
    assertThat("result should be blablabla", result, is("blablabla");
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but I already had it, my doubt is how to perform the test